# Работа атрибута DataSource в #

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Не могу найти хорошего объяснения работы атрибута `[DataSource]`. Везде работа с таблицами. А если я хочу просто туда загрузить пару переменных без таблиц, то как быть? и как к этим переменным обращаться в самом `[TestMetod]`?

Comment: свойство DataSource есть у многих контроллов, уточните какой именно вас интересует : DataGridView или ComboBox или какой то еще ?

Comment: хмм, прошу прощение. Я атрибут использую в Unit тесте для передачи параметров в сам тест.

Comment: @Сергей вот пример с msdn `[DataSource(@"Provider=Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.4.0; Data Source=C:\Data\MathsData.sdf;", "Numbers")]  
[TestMethod()]  
public void AddIntegers_FromDataSourceTest()  
{  
    var target = new Maths();  
  
    // Access the data  
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["FirstNumber"]);  
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["SecondNumber"]);   
    int expected = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["Sum"]);  
    int actual = target.IntegerMethod(x, y);  
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); 
   }`  но тут используют БД

Comment: @Сергей а мне же нужно чтобы я сам создавал переменные, определял их и заносил в `[TestMetod]`, без использования внешних файлов.

Comment: Используйте NUnit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С использованием mstest - никак нельзя сразу внести переменные без использования сторонних файлов. Обычно создают один файл .xlsx и в разных вкладках добавляют данные для разных тестов. В итоге получается один файл с данными для всех тестов, которые не перемешаны между собой.

Answer (score 2):

Назначение атрибута `[DataSource]` — получать информацию именно из таблиц. ВЫ описываете ваши табличные данные в этом атрибуте, в результате ваш тестовый метод будет вызван по разу для каждой из строк таблицы.

Для того, чтобы получить доступ к информации из вашей строки таблицы внутри теста, нужно в тестовом классе использовать свойство `TestContext`, и в нём обращаться к `DataRow`.

Пример:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest04052017
{
    // convention: needed to get the data for data-driven test
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", 
                SubDir + @"\Tests.csv", @"Tests#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    public void TestingAlphaCentauriDistance()
    {
        var coordX = (double)TestContext.DataRow[0];
        var coordY = (double)TestContext.DataRow[1];
        var expected = (double)TestContext.DataRow[2];

        var dx = coordX - 77777;
        var dy = coordX - 99999;

        var distance = Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        DoubleAssert.AreClose(distance, expected, eps);
    }
}
```

Если вы хотите воспользоваться просто конкретным набором значений, вам нужно разрефакторить ваш тест, чтобы он принимал значения на вход:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest04052017
{
    // convention: needed to get the data for data-driven test
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", 
                SubDir + @"\Tests.csv", @"Tests#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    public void TestingAlphaCentauriDistance()
    {
        var coordX = (double)TestContext.DataRow[0];
        var coordY = (double)TestContext.DataRow[1];
        var expected = (double)TestContext.DataRow[2];

        TestMain(coordX, coordY, expected);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestingRandomDistance()
    {
        TestMain(1, 2, 300);
        TestMain(2, 1, 400);
    }

    void TestMain(double coordX, double coordY, double expected)
    {
        var dx = coordX - 77777;
        var dy = coordX - 99999;

        var distance = Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        DoubleAssert.AreClose(distance, expected, eps);
    }
}
```